# Javascript to open link in new popup window

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a theme in wordpress and creating inline sharing buttons at the bottom of posts but I am stuck at a point.
I want to open link in new popup window using javascript.
Here is the html code.

```
    <ul>
  <li>
    <a href="//somesite.com/" rel="nofollow" class="social_share_link">Share</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the javascript

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
$("a.social_share_link").on("click",function(){
    var share_link = $(this).prop('href');
    window.open(share_link,'','scrollbars=1,height=500,width=500,left=500,top=100');
     });
</script>
```

Please help me.

Comment: I don't see a question asked.

Comment: He wrote "I want to open link in new popup window using javascript."

Comment: Funny, I thought his question was an answer, as the code is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is your working code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="//somesite.com/" rel="nofollow" class="social_share_link">Share</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

these are the changes you will need to do:

```
$("a.social_share_link").on("click", function() {
  var share_link = $(this).prop('href');
  console.log(share_link);
window.open(share_link, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");

});
```

you can also refer the Working Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/9wua66mw/

Comment: @ShivamShukla :) can you please vote this answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Just simple call onclick event**

> 1. Without extra scripts (Inline)

```
<a href="//somesite.com/"  class="social_share_link"
onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'somesite', 'width=500,height=500')"
target="_blank">Share</a>
```

> 2. With extra scripts & jquery`

```
<a href="//somesite.com/"  class="social_share_link" target="_blank">Share</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".social_share_link").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var share_link = $(this).prop('href');
      window.open(share_link, "social_share", "width=500,height=500");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: This is what i'm avoiding. My customer didn't want onclick into anchor. Just need javascript

Answer (score 0):

Prevent default event--redirecting to wherever `href` attribute points to--using

```
$("a.social_share_link").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var share_link = $(this).prop('href');
    window.open(share_link, '', 'scrollbars=1,height=500,width=500,left=500,top=100');
});
```

Comment: What you like to explain what *"not working"* mean!? I can think of hundreds of reasons why your snippet not working

Comment: I mean to say that event is not working in this, i already tried it and that's why i am here.

Comment: I have tried it and seems to work. Other parts of your code could be causing the problem. Otherwise, it must work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, try to use the attribute `_blank` or check the developer tools, maybe you have an error that you can't see.
I tested your code and it works fine.

here is the demo with `_blank` attibute: https://jsfiddle.net/quethzel/L1jerwo1/2/